# Java version when multiple JDKs exist on windows machine

Tags: java, windows, cmd

Given

- Multiple JDKs intalled in my Windows machine.. say JDK X, JDK Y,.. etc
- Environment variables *JAVA_HOME* & *PATH* are pointing to JDK X.

Action

- `java -version` at cmd, it printed JDK Y at console.

Expectation

- want `java -version` to print JDK X

What am I missing, so that it should print JDK X ?

[image]

Comment: Check if JAVA_HOME & PATH are pointing to correct location of JDK X.

Comment: @kann Yes they are. Double checked this. Also, a mismatch here, i believe, would not had let me recognize java command at cmd

Comment: Try `where java` on the command line to see which executable it picks. I think some common installs put a `java.exe` in `C:\Windows\System32` for some reason ...

Comment: @JoachimSauer It returned me two location 1)C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath 2) exe at Java Home path location

Comment: @JoachimSauer location C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath has 3 exe in it java, javaw, javaws

Comment: Can you show your PATH variable?

Comment: @Chris94 It has just 'bin' appended to JAVA_HOME.

Comment: @Chris94 JAVA_HOME points to the JDK X, as expected ! Check image above

Comment: I meant your whole path.  Have you checked it carefully for other java locations earlier in the path than this one?

Comment: What JDKs did you install? Oracle or OpenJDK or IBM? How did you install? Was it via an installer, i.e. an executable file? Or did you simply extract a ZIP file? In what order did you install your JDKs? Which did you install first, which second, etc.

Comment: @Abra It is Hotspot, through installer. jdk1.8.0_221 installed first. jdk1.8.0_161 installed recently

Comment: The "Oracle" JDK appears first in your PATH. That is the one that will be used.